# "C'est la vie" (such is life) in Chinese

Tags: translation, idioms

On Wiktionary there are two ways listed for saying "such is life" / "c'est la vie" in Chinese. Both look like literal translations:

1. 這就是生活, 这就是生活 (zhè jiùshì shēnghuó)
2. 生活就是這樣, 生活就是这样 (shēnghuó jiùshì zhèyàng)

But when I get Google Translate to translate "c'est la vie" from English to Chinese it produces two more options:

1. (上)力威 (either with or without the "上")

I realize the phrase is originally French of course but it's very common in English. I'm curious to know whether this has any meaning at all in Chinese since I can't make sense of it.

Comment: 力威 has no real Chinese meaning. Apparently it is just a phonetic translation of `la vie'.

Comment: At least you should use french translator=,=

Comment: Obviously "(上)力威" is a mistake of Google translate. "这就是生活" is correct.

Comment: The problem with French to Chinese translators like Google Translate is that they actually translate to English as an intermediary step. It's one of the most common loan phrases used in English so I was curious to see how it was handled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"(上)力威" has no meaning in Chinese. "這就是生活/这就是生活/生活就是這樣/生活就是这样" is correct.

Comment: Upvoted. The direct literal translation is the best here.

Comment: For a more idiomatic (but fatalistic) version, you can try "这就是命".

Comment: Agree with @congusbongus, in Chinese it's more like 'such is destiny' "这就是命"

Answer (score 4):

If you mean something along the lines of "what're ya gonna do", then I think 没办法 also works. However, saying 这就是命 or 这就是生活, as some posters above have noted both sound correct to me.

Comment: Yes, in the resigned sense of 'oh well, that's just how things are, there's nothing we can do about it.'   没办法 seems the most idiomatic/natural alternative to me.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was going for. I guess it is the pessimistic POV.

Answer (score 2):

The correct translation of " this is **life**" isn't " 這就是*生活*" but "這就是**人生**"
people often confused 生活 (living) with 生命 (a life) and 人生(one's life)

As of "這就是命", it is translated as " this is fate"  in English .
命 as in 命運 (fate)